# Meaning of "close boarded"/"close board"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I've seen the following example sentence for one of the meanings of strut, "Brace (something) with a strut or struts.":

> the holes were **close-boarded** and strutted

The sentence is from [Oxford dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/strut)

(EDIT: ...and without any further context.)

I haven't found *close-boarded* or *close-board* in any dictionary. I have found, however, the term "close board fencing". Does *close-boarded* mean here that close board fences were put up around the holes (and generally mean "to put up a close board fence")?

Comment: The holes of what? Does the sentence give that context? It does appear to be a term related to privacy fencing. But you'd have to put the struts on the posts *before* close-boarding, so I'd expect to see *strutted and close-boarded* if it were fencing.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no more context given for this sentence. In fact, it's the only example sentence given in the dictionary for this meaning, which, in the Oxford dictionaries, is always an indication that the usage is rare (even if it is for "strut" here).

Comment: It's a bit odd that your dictionary doesn't specifically define ***close-boarded***, given they use the term in their example usages for other words. But if you couldn't extrapolate the meaning from their entries for [***close***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/close) *(With very little or no space in between)* and [***boarded***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/boarded) *(covered or sealed with pieces of wood)*, there's always [***close-board fence***.](http://www.treeterms.co.uk/definitions/close-board-fence)

Comment: Well that's at least something; I had tried to look up a definition for "close-board fence" with OneLook Dictionary search and couldn't find that, either.

Comment: Why didn't you supply any context from the outset??

Comment: @Lambie Sorry if I haven't understood your question correctly. I hadn't any context for the example sentence in my post. The last paragraph in my post had been included from the beginning. I've added "(EDIT: ...and without any further context.)" later between the example sentence and the last paragraph. So besides that addition and cosmetical changes there weren't additions of context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... it may be worthwhile considering a **close-boarded** roof.  This means covering the rafters with softwood boarding or ply sheathing before felting, battening, and tiling, providing an extra layer of weather resistance.  [source](https://books.google.com/books?id=C5o-44bFQ90C&pg=PA111&lpg=PA111&dq=close+board+roofing&source=bl&ots=F9m5KdxVDy&sig=r2JqJH8XFyTXv5plud-yD62BVT8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjWg6D2gonVAhVJ4mMKHXZ2DDkQ6AEIRzAF#v=onepage&q=close%20board%20roofing&f=false)

You'll probably have to look up some of the other roof-related jargon (*felting, battening*) in the sentence.  The article goes on to state that this kind of roof was popular in the 1920s and 1930s but is not now because the boards often rot due to poor air flow, and have to be replaced.

So, "close-board" is not a term most native English speakers -- or anyone other than professional roofers -- would know.

(Edit) *Close-boarding* seems to be a carpentry term meaning to lay the boards so their edges partially overlap, as compared with *open-boarding* which leaves space between the boards.  So a [close-boarded fence](http://www.howefencing.co.uk/uploads/cache/590x443-prod_fen_closeboard_panel.gif) vs. an [open-boarded fence](http://bigfishfence.com/files/2014/08/dog_eared_space_board_panel_with_post_550x3003.jpg).

Comment: Thanks. It seems I'm developing a "taste" for questions about terms that most native English speakers wouldn't know...

Comment: @Turpidude  It's a fair question.  You don't know that it's esoteric until you ask  :)

Comment: @Turpidude Also please see my edit, as it seems "close-boarding" applies to all carpentry, not just roofing.

Answer (score 3):

The sentence looks like a roof repair context.

[Here](http://www.1stassociated.co.uk/close-boarding.asp) is a document that describes close board roofing.

Comment: The document you linked to is an excellent source.  This answer would be improved if you summarized some of what it says, in case it one day goes offline.

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting. I only saw later on Google Books that "close-boarded" appears also in a roofing context.